# Endpoints not showing in my site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, endpoints

I would like to ask. I got problem with endpoints like order-received etd. That not working correctly and when i hit them its showing like The page you requested cannot be found!.

Please If somebody have experience how to solve this problem let me answer ASAP.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Show us an example of what's happening.

Comment: Did you manage to get this sorted out? I'm having a similar issue. Not a 404, but just showing the my-account page.